# new Regexp doesn't work

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to convert following expression to "new Regexp()" style:

http://jsfiddle.net/HDWBZ/

```
var Wyrazenie = /\btest[a-z]*/g;
```

I'm really confused with it and have no idea how to fix it. Below is what I've done but obviously it doesn't work.

```
var Wyraznie = new RegExp("\btest[a-z]*","g");
```

Also have a question how would it look if instead of "test" I would use variable?

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time. Create a separate SO question for each separate question (sounds logical, right?).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use this instead...

```
new RegExp("\\btest[a-z]*", "g");
```

... as `\b` will be interpolated into a *single* (slashless) character when JavaScript parser works through the corresponding string literal. The solution is to escape slash itself.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/HDWBZ/1/

Comment: @raina77ow Thanks for the edit. You forestalled me :)

Comment: thank you, works perfect! Regarding to second part: new RegExp("\\b"+test+"[a-z]*", "g");, where test is variable

Comment: Thanks man it works poperly 
let myString = " Tata Nexon EV Tata"
let myVariable = "Tata"
let myReg = new RegExp("\\b"+myVariable , "g")
let myMatch = myString.match(myReg)
console.log(myMatch)